# Stencil IncrSat and DecrSat explanation

Tags: unity, masking, stencil

Can someone please explain me what is the purpose of IncrSat and DecrSat?

Currently I know that they increment/decrement the current value in the buffer and they make sure the value is between 0 and 255, but I want to know how can I use them.

Could you please give a simple example and explain how IncrSat or DecrSat can help?